# How not to trim lines when printing environment variables in powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

To print environment in PowerShell I can do, according to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-windows-powershell-to-display-all-environment-variables/):

```
dir env:
```

So I did, and for example for `Path` and for other environment variables longer then my window I see:

```
 Path                      C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;...
```

I do not want `...`, I want to see the full length anything there is value of environment variable of all variables.

I tried to read: https://superuser.com/questions/1049531/how-to-fix-truncated-powershell-output-even-when-ive-specified-width-300 and tried to `cd env: -Width 1000`, or tried `cd env:` and then `Get-ChildItem -Width 1000`, it does not work, and searched google but with no success. The `dir env: | Out-String -width 999` results in an endless amount of empty lines. What works is `dir env: | cat`, but then the names of variables disappear.

Is there any way I can view not-truncated values of all environment variables with variable names?

Comment: `$env:Path` will resolve the value on it's own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your question literally, if you just want to **view** the env variables with their untruncated values on the console, you can simply format the output as list:

```
Get-ChildItem env: | Format-List
```

This will display the information in the following fashion and insert visual line breaks if the value is longer than the available space:

```
Name  : PSModulePath
Value : C:\Users\{and so on}
```

Answer (score 1):

`out-string` behaves slightly differently on Windows PowerShell versus PowerShell Core - it looks like PowerShell Core uses `-Width` as a *maximum* width whereas Windows PowerShell *pads* each line to the specified width so you're seeing each environment variable separated by a *lot* of spaces.

**PowerShell Core**

```
PS 7.1.3> dir env: | out-string -width 9999

Name                           Value
----                           -----
ALLUSERSPROFILE                C:\ProgramData
APPDATA                        C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles             C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)        C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432             C:\Program Files\Common Files
```

**Windows PowerShell**

```
PS 5.1> dir env: | out-string -width 9999

Name                           Value
----                           -----
ALLUSERSPROFILE                C:\ProgramData




APPDATA                        C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming




CommonProgramFiles             C:\Program Files\Common Files




CommonProgramFiles(x86)        C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files




CommonProgramW6432             C:\Program Files\Common Files
```

(padding not to scale!)

It's a bit ugly, but if you want to make Windows PowerShell output look the same you can do something like this:

```
PS> ((dir env: | format-table | out-string -width 9999) -split [System.Environment]::NewLine).Trim() -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
```

Basically, split the output into lines, trim them and then join them back together again.